# Can objects have access modifiers?

Tags: java, oop

I was going through a piece of code when I came across this:

```
public class ClassicA {
   private static ClassicA instance = null;
}
```

I have never used such a thing and wanted to know what it means and how it is used. Also, what is the purpose of the access modifier for the object? Any examples/links are welcome.

Comment: probably in that class there's a static getter for the instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably means that `ClassicA` is a Singleton. It is usually involved with declaring a private constructor, and a single public static `getInstance()` method.

Singletons are used when you want to make sure there is only one global instance of `ClassicA` in your entire application. Instead of instantiating it, you call `getInstance()`, which will check if it was instantiated once or not. If it was, it will instantiate it, and store the the resulting object in the private `instance` field. If it was already constructed, just return the `instance` field without re-instantiating.

Note that this is considered bad practice. See: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40373/so-singletons-are-bad-then-what

Comment: Well, strictly speaking this doesn't mean that the class is singleton: there might be a public constructor. I assume that class source code is not complete, otherwise it would not make much sense.

Comment: @Truth: Thanks, I got that hence deleted my comment :-)

Answer (score 3):

Well, the class `ClassicA` has a private and static field `instance` which is null.
If there are no getters/setters the only way to access that field would be using reflection.

Since this looks like a singleton, I guess there's a getter as well that returns `instance` and if it is null first creates an instance and assigns it to the field.

Answer (score 1):

its a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)
basically the author intended there to be only 1 instance of this class alive (the instance field)
the constructor is probably private and used only within the class.

Comment: It's generally more helpful if you write at bit of a description, rather than just posting a link.

Answer (score 1):

It's a (static) member of the class, and yes, [these can have access modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). (And as others have noted, it indeed looks like a portion of a Singleton.)

Answer (score 1):

This is used typically for a class that exhibits the [Singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

The point is that for these types of objects you only want a single instance at most. What you do is create a private constructor for the class and then usually a public static method called, getInstance in which you check if the private instance variable has been set yet or not. If it has not yet set, you create a new instance of the class and assign it to instance, then you return that instance. If the object was already created you simply return it.  Like this:

```
public class MySingleton {

  private static MySingleton instance=null;
  private MySingleton() {
     //do stuff
  }

  public static MySingleton getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
       instance = new MySingleton();

    }
    return instance;
  }

}
```

Then from throughout your program you can easily get the singleton object from anywhere.

Thus, a singleton is effectively just a glorified global variable in languages such as PHP. I would argue though that it is a lot cleaner as you can prevent others from reassigning the reference to the instance and other trickery that may be very bad from a design standpoint.

Typically people use it for classes that manage some type of data access, such as a DB object, for Factory classes and builder classes, see [this](http://codeofdoom.com/wordpress/2008/04/20/how-and-when-to-use-singleton-classes/) for more info

Comment: public syncrhonized? Or just use synchronized(MySingleton.class)? around getInstance?

Comment: That would do it (the two are essentially equivalent), though it would add a synchronization bottleneck (which may not be a big deal). Another approach would be to do [double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java) -- but note especially the need to make `instance` a `volatile`. But the best approach would probably be to not lazy-load at all: `private static MySingleton instance = new MySingleton()`. That initializer is itself lazily loaded (it's only run when you load the class, which is when you first use it), which should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is used for singleton pattern. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: I would expect a better answer from a 10k user.

Comment: @juergend: In which case you don't post an incomplete answer.

Answer (score 0):

`private static` means that the `instance` is available to all the instances and static methods of the class, but only to them. It's actually like having static private method.

Such tricks can be used for example for implementing a singleton: you keep internally a single instance of a class, and you can give it to the class's clients on demand. Or for any other case when you need something shared just between the static methods and instances of some class.